# Connecting to AWS Aurora MySQL using Sequel Pro

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, sequelpro, amazon-aurora

I've just created a  AWS Aurora MySQL with this end point:

```
tdk.cwob1oxhu1so.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com
```

DB instance: `tdk`

which I want to connect from a Sequel Pro client

So I put  `tdk.cwob1oxhu1so.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com` in the Host, the user, the port and `tdk` as Database, but I got this error: `Unknown database 'tdk'`

Comment: Don't specify a database name when you connect.  database != instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In AWS, the database instance and the database are two different things. The database instance is the actual database server that you are creating on AWS, and the database is the schema that you create on that server. To find the name of your database, go to your RDS homepage (https://console.aws.amazon.com/rds/home), click on your instance, and scroll down to find `DB Name`.